# Why XmlHttpRequest readyState = 2 on 200 HTTP response code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-200

So I'm using plain javascript (no jquery), to send a file to the server.  Server script PHP returns status code 200 at the end, but instead javascript is getting readyState == 2.

The PHP code sends back status code 200:

```
header('X-PHP-Response-Code: 200', true, 200);
exit;
```

The javascript is doing:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            var message;
            switch(request.status) {
                case '200':
                     message = "Data uploaded successfully.";
                break;

                case '406':
                    message = "Incorrect file format.  Please try again.";
                break;

                case '410':
                    message = "Unexpected error.  Please contact support.";
                break;

                default:
                break;
            }
            status_message_container.innerHTML = message;
            submit_button.disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            alert( "Unexpected error:  " + this.statusText + ".\nPlease try again");
        }
    };

    request.send(formData);
```

Even know the HTTP 200 status code comes back correctly (I get 'OK') on frontend.  The JS script is seeing `readyState==2` (i.e. else block always hit)

My understanding is that a server status code of 200 should give `readyState == 4`??

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, `onreadystate` isn't just fired once. It's fired multiple times, you need to be able to handle that. These are the codes you need to handle:

0 UNSENT - *open()has not been called yet*
1 OPENED - *send()has not been called yet*
2 HEADERS_RECEIVED - *send() has been called, and headers and status are available*
3 LOADING Downloading; - *responseText holds partial data*
4 - *The operation is complete*

Your code is hitting the else block on `readyState == 2` (headers received) and assuming that is an error status when it's not.

You error check should be inside the `request.readyState == 4` check. That way, the request is complete but there could also have been an error:

```
if (request.readyState == 4) {
    switch(request.status) {
        case '200':
            message = "Data uploaded successfully.";
        break;
        // Error handling here
        default: alert( "Unexpected error:  " + this.statusText + ".\nPlease try again"); break;
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I realise `onreadystate` hits multiple times - anytime readyState changes in fact. Specifically I'm wondering why **readyState isn't 4** when I sent back HTTP 200? Isn't the operation **completed** by then?  If not, what indicator does the server script have to give to get `readyState == 4`?
_EDIT:_ Your code will fail because readyState == 2 on HTTP status 200.

Comment: Your readyState probably did hit the completed block, eventually. It's just that it'll hit the "error" part first when it receives the error. It should always receive a *done* when a response is received - whether or not it's an error is defined by its response code. Updated answer to better explain that

Comment: My code won't fail. readyState is *both* 2 (when the headers are received) **and** 4 (when the response has been downloaded) when *any* status code is returned.

Comment: Is there any readystate will tell request is sent out successfully from OPENED? if readysate 2 means HEADERS_RECEIVED, means it got the response header already?