# ajax GET request responseText empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to create a chatbox using AJAX but for some reason my xhttp.responseText is empty. In firebug I can see that a GET request is being sent and it even responds with the correct text, but this text just doesn't get put in the responseText for some reason.

Here is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chatroom</title>
    <script>

    function setup() {
        ajaxRequest( 'GET', 'loadmessages.php', updateChat);
        setInterval(function () {
            ajaxRequest( 'GET', 'loadmessages.php', updateChat);
        }, 1000);
    }

    function updateChat(xhttp) {
        document.getElementById( 'chat' ).innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }

    function ajaxRequest( method, file, cfunc ) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(xhttp.readyState == 2 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                cfunc(xhttp);
            }
        }
        xhttp.open( method, file, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="setup();">
    <div id="chat">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is loadmessages.php:

```
<?php 

include( 'connect.php' );


$query = "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
    $output = "";
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $content = $row['content'];
        $time = $row['time'];

        $output .= "[sent by $name on $time] $content <hr/>";
    }
    echo $output;
} else {
    echo "No messages yet, be the first to send one!";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

And the connect.php:

```
<?php 

$conn = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'chatroom' ) or die( 'Couldn\'t connect to database!' );

?>
```

Since there's nothing in the database yet, it just echoes "No messages yet, be the first to send one!". I can see this response if I open firebug, but this text is not in the responseText variable.

Comment: Do you get anything when you open loadmessages.php directly at your browser

Comment: Yes it shows "No messages yet, be the first to send one!" on the page, as it should, since there's nothing in the database

Comment: any error in console??

Comment: You said that firebug shows the GET request has the correct text. Did you inspect the xhttp variable in the debugger?

Comment: Nope, all firebug is giving me is the GET request with the correct response.

Comment: No I did not, let me see @LeeJenkins 
EDIT: Now this is very interesting, inspecting the xhttp variable, it does say that responseText should be "No messages yet, be the first to send one!" even though it doesn't return anything if I reference xhttp.responseText in JavaScript.

Comment: xhttp.readyState == 4 is the answer ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the `if` clause for `readyState` like below:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xhttp.readyState == 4) {
        cfunc(xhttp);
    }
}
```

since this callback is triggered everytime the `readyState` changes and you are testing for the value `2` which is `sent`, at this point there is no response available in `xhttp.responseText`

See here [What do the different readystates in XMLHttpRequest mean, and how can I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632774/what-do-the-different-readystates-in-xmlhttprequest-mean-and-how-can-i-use-them)

In slightly more detail here [Why XmlHttpRequest readyState = 2 on 200 HTTP response code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419888/why-xmlhttprequest-readystate-2-on-200-http-response-code)
the difference between `readyState==2` and `readyState==4`

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using jQuery for AJAX, because it is far more simple and intuitive. Here is link for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

Comment: I'm trying to step away from jQuery with this project. I know the power of jQuery and how much easier it is but the whole point of me creating this project is to not use jQuery for once. Thanks anyway!

Comment: ok, I just recommended in case that you don't know about jquery.

Comment: @fico7489 I think everyone has heard of jQuery :)

Comment: When I am looking at new questions I don't think so ;)